Some pipewire apps are quiet
Somehow, I have saved an audio preference in pipewire that the SuperCollider Server should be very quiet. How do I remove this setting? Or at least change the amplitude in the moment?
How do I apply it on purpose to different apps?
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with the Ubuntu Studio packages installed.
ETA:
It's possible to sort this out for SuperCollider specifically by launching it with the command pw-jack scide, which runs it in jack emulation. Hwever, I'd still like to know the solution to the larger/underlying problem.
